# Mass rewrite commits

Tags: git

I'm cleaning up a middle sized repository for a public release.

One of the issues is that although all commits are from me, the author and committer differs a lot (I had inconsistent configuration across machines).

Is there an easy way to rewrite this information in the commits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible (although very dangerous), with the `filter-branch` command.

An example is described in the Pro Git book: http://progit.org/book/ch6-4.html (see the last paragraph at the bottom of the page).

But again: we very cautious, because you're rewriting history and commits (and thus sha1 hashes)....

Comment: If other coders are not relying on the SHA1s (the repo is not public) the rewriting does not matter. Make a backup copy of the repo before doing this!

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't find any easy way to do so, but I would also be surprised if it would be possible: this kind of information (author, message, notes), in fact, is part of the bunch of bytes used to calculate the SHA-1 signature of each commit. This means that, changing these info on any but the least commit, will move you on a new branch, and this is not what you want, I suppose.

Comment: Actually I would be OK with that. I'm preparing the repo for public release, so rewriting history isn't an issue yet.